# WebApi + AngularJS: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: angularjs, web-config, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a problem and although I've seen plenty of answers to the same topic nothing really worked.. I have a WebAPI project and an MVC one where I have Angular.

From the Angular project, I'm trying to post something like this:

```
var promise = $http.post("http://localhost:55692/api/users", user)
                .success(function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                });

            $http(
        {
            url: "http://localhost:55692/api/users",
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: { "user": user }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                debugger;
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            });
            return promise;
```

If you see, I'm calling the same API twice in case it's an Angular thing but to me, it's not..

I have this controller in my API project:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage LoginOrRegister(RegisterUserViewModel user)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

This is the response I have:

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ynD.png)

And this is my WebConfig

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <!--<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />-->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Token, X-Acting-As" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

**EDIT**
My WebApiConfig looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Attribute routing enabled
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Convention-based routing enabled
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;

            // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
            // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
            // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
            //config.EnableQuerySupport();

            // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
            // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
    }
```

Finally, the only thing "weird" is that I'm using IISExpress as these are the first steps of my project..

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: What does your `Register` method in `WebApiConfig.cs` look like? Also, just as a general point of advice, I would avoid creating route prefixes that don't match your controller names. When your project grows it will become increasingly frustrating to navigate your code when the controller name doesn't match the route prefix. Even more so if you are working on a team.

Comment: There, I added it.. You have a point there but honestly it's just a test controller to get the cross domain thing work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well after a lot of struggle, this was it...

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Attribute routing enabled
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Convention-based routing enabled
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new PreflightRequestsHandler()); 
}
    }
```

And the preflight class:

```
public class PreflightRequestsHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request.Headers.Contains("Origin") && request.Method.Method.Equals("OPTIONS"))
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
                // Define and add values to variables: origins, headers, methods (can be global)               
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, content-type");

                var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                tsc.SetResult(response);
                return tsc.Task;
            }
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

    }
```

I hope this helps anyone else!

Answer (score 0):

405 comes up when your request data type not supported. You need to pass content type  in following

```
private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

return this.http.post(this.baseUserUrl + '/Save', JSON.stringify(user), this.options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response)
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
```

and at API layer

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Save(UserDto user)
```

or

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Save(UserDto user)
```

Comment: I have another project working with API and Angular and I didn't need to do all that.. In fact that's why this error is so weird to me..